# Why is this "if A then B end" statement not accepted with jq 1.6?

Tags: json, jq

According to the `jq` manual (Conditionals and Comparisons > if-then-else):

> `if A then B end` is the same as `if A then B else . end`. That is, the
>   else branch is optional, and if absent is the same as ..

The same is  substantiated by the accepted answer to this Stack Overflow question: [JSON JQ if without else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949184/json-jq-if-without-else)

So **why does this `if A then B end` statement invoke a parse error?**

```
$ jq --version
jq-1.6
$ echo 2 | jq 'if . == 0 then "zero" end'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
if . == 0 then "zero" end                      
jq: error: Possibly unterminated 'if' statement at <top-level>, line 1:
if . == 0 then "zero" end
jq: 2 compile errors
$ echo 0 | jq 'if . == 0 then "zero" end'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
if . == 0 then "zero" end                      
jq: error: Possibly unterminated 'if' statement at <top-level>, line 1:
if . == 0 then "zero" end
jq: 2 compile errors
```

What I understand to be the *equivalent* `if A then B else . end` form of the statement seems to work:

```
$ echo 2 | jq 'if . == 0 then "zero" else . end'
2
$ echo 0 | jq 'if . == 0 then "zero" else . end'
"zero"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking at the [manual for the development version of jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#if-then-else-end), rather than [the manual for jq version 1.6](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#if-then-else-end).

Comment: This answer is not precise: the issue was that OP was not using `else .` because it’s implicit in the dev version but not in the 1.6 version.